# After adding js file with the custom module in magento,checkout page is not working

Tags: javascript, magento-1.9, cryptoapi, cryptojs

I want to add the js file along with the custom module.After adding it in layout file of my module.Payment method stop to work.Can somebody tell me what is the problem.
here is the code-
custom_layout.xml

```
     <?xml version="1.0"?>
     <layout version="0.1.0">
     <default>
     <reference name="head">
     <action method="addJs"><script>custom_module/crypto.js</script>
     </action>   
     </reference>
     </default>
     </layout>
```

config.xml

```
    <frontend>
    <layout>
    <updates>
     <ideal>
     <file>custom_layout.xml</file>
        </ideal>
    </updates>
     </layout>
     </frontend>
```

After adding crypto js,it is available in header but checkout page is not working.here is the screenshots-
[screenshot of console](https://i.stack.imgur.com/eSTxb.png)

[screenshot of non clickable checkout page](https://i.stack.imgur.com/MqZpk.png)

Answer (score 2):

I think its conflict issue so you can add group of js like

```
<action  method="addItem">
<type>js</type><name>custom_module/crypto.js</name>
<group>cust_js</group>
</action>
```

try to add js mentioned as above. This will fix conflict issue hope its help :)